# jquery fancybox - editing the main .js file doesn't change site behaviour

Tags: jquery, fancybox, settings, default

I hope there's a simple answer for someone who knows his way around, as I'm newer to this.

Situation:
my template calls this fancybox:

But when I change something in the file, it doesn't reflect on the site. For example, I change default settings like these

```
    titlePosition : 'outside', // 'float', 'outside', 'inside' or 'over'
    titleFromAlt : true ,
```

(before they were float and false)

But the actual result on the site remains the original setting. Nor does adding the code into the header help:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'  : 'outside'
});
```

So my guess is that the theme is pulling some other default settings from elsewhere, but I don't know how to locate that section.

Any suggestions will help a lot!
thanks,
Lukas

Comment: have you tried: `$("a.fancybox").fancybox({  titlePosition  : 'outside' });` (no quotes around titlePosition) and are you calling this on document ready?  Also which version of fancybox are you using - 1 or 2?

Comment: Hey Pete, it's fancybox 1 (the template came with it and doesn't have a UI way to upgrade to fancybox 2. Upgrading manually (replacing the jquery files) breaks things, as the template uses fancybox for more than just images it seems).

I wasn't calling it on document ready, now I (think) I am:

this is in my <head>:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({ titlePosition : 'outside' });  
});
</script>

But this is ok now - I have installed "easy fancybox" plugin and that works with the template, and let's me change the settings in a UI.